# How to add a SearchWidget to the ActionBar?

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, android-actionbar, searchview

I'm trying to add a Search-ActionView to my application (as explained here http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/search/search-dialog.html#UsingSearchWidget). Unfortunately I keep getting a NullPointerException and I'm having a hard time detecting what's actually going wrong.

I created a searchable config and a searchable activity as shown on the android page. My menu .xml file looks like this:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    ...
    <item
        android:id="@+id/menu_item_search"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon_search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="@string/action_bar_button_search">
    </item>

</menu>
```

This is the method where the Exception is thrown:

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
{
    MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
    menuInflater.inflate( R.menu.action_bar, menu );

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).getActionView();

    // NullPointerException thrown here; searchView is null.
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
    searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );
}
```

Complete stack trace:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.activities.Test.onCreateOptionsMenu(Test.java:41)
at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2444)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.preparePanel(PhoneWindow.java:408)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.invalidatePanelMenu(PhoneWindow.java:759)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$1.run(PhoneWindow.java:2997)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:790)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:557)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post whole code ? have you implement searchable configuration and searchable activity as discussed in document ?

Comment: As written above: searchable xml and searchable activity are set and added to the Manifest. Line 41 is the one that I commented with "NullPointerException thrown here; searchView is null."

Comment: So the problem is actually that **menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search).getActionView()** keeps returning null.

Comment: what is the menu file name, as per code  R.menu.`action_bar`, and as per description  My `menu .xml` file looks like this

Comment: just confirming as everything else looking fine.....

Answer (score 20, accepted):

use this way as in [link](http://www.edumobile.org/android/android-development/action-bar-search-view/)

```
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar, menu);
        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.menu_item_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();


        SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        if(null!=searchManager ) {   
         searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));
        }
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);

        return true;
    }
```

Comment: ok just change the id to menu_item_search_1 to both place then clean & built project and run that ...

Comment: http://www.java2s.com/Code/Android/UI/UsageofSearchViewinanActionBarasamenuitem.htm

Comment: I didn't figure out what exactly was going wrong but another few tries of renaming, building and cleaning resolved the issue somehow. I probably had some stupid slips somewhere..

Comment: I have tried this solution, but still the searchView in the line   `searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager...  `  is null. How can I get to the actual SearchView as defined in the menu.xml file?

Comment: This doesn't seem to solve the problem, and the code formatting is odd...

Answer (score 49):

Since this question is looked up quite often and I stumbled across the very same problem again and again here is a little follow up that keeps track of all necessary steps to create a SearchWidget.

There is one tricky part about the SearchWidget though: **If you use hardcoded Strings in the searchable.xml instead of resources the app will crash with a confusing error message.** This took me way too many hours of my life...

1. Create an Activity to handle the search results

   ```
   public class Search extends Activity {}
   ```
2. Add a file "searchable.xml" to your res/xml directory (**use resources for hint & label!**)

   ```
   <searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       android:hint="@string/search_hint"
       android:includeInGlobalSearch="false"
       android:label="@string/search_label"
       android:searchSettingsDescription="@string/search_global_description" />
   ```
3. Create the proper menu item "main.xml" in you res/menu directory

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

       <item
          android:id="@+id/options_menu_main_search"
          android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
          android:icon="@drawable/icon_magnifier"
          android:showAsAction="always"
          android:title="Search"/>

   </menu>
   ```
4. Update your Manifest.xml: Add the search activity and specify which activities may receive search intents. Adding `<meta-data android:name="android.app.default_searchable" android:value=".app.Search" />` to an `activity` node makes it searchable. Adding it to the `application` node makes all activities searchable.

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
       <application>
           <meta-data
               android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
               android:value=".app.Search" />

           <activity android:name=".activities.Search" >
               <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
           </intent-filter>

           <meta-data
               android:name="android.app.searchable"
               android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
       </activity>
   </application>
   ```
5. Add the SearchManager to your ActionView in every activity that should provide the SearchWidget

   ```
   public class Activity extends android.app.Activity
   {
       @Override
       public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu( Menu menu )
       {
           getMenuInflater().inflate( R.menu.main, menu );

           // Add SearchWidget.
           SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService( Context.SEARCH_SERVICE );
           SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem( R.id.options_menu_main_search ).getActionView();

           searchView.setSearchableInfo( searchManager.getSearchableInfo( getComponentName() ) );

           return super.onCreateOptionsMenu( menu );
       }
   }
   ```

Comment: Clearest example I've seen

Comment: It would help me if step 1 was elaborated; that's the part I'm having trouble with.

Answer (score 24):

If you are using targeting **Android 2.x** and using **android.support.v7.widget.SearchView**
check that your menu.xml looks like this (note the **yourapp** namespace)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="@string/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        yourapp:showAsAction="always"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

And in the Activity where you inflate the menu use:

```
android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) 
MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.search));
```

Comment: This should be marked as the correct answer, the first answer makes no sense it is the searchView that is null not the searchManager.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. You repaired my current temper.

Answer (score 8):

[SearchView getActionView returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407171/searchview-getactionview-returning-null)

As in the link, open your menu xml file and change

```
android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

into

```
app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"
```

this worked for me

Answer (score 2):

I also got the same problem. In my case, change `android:actionViewClass` to `app:actionViewClass` solved the problem
(with `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` in `<menu>` tag).

Answer (score 1):

First of all, create an XML file containing the SearchWidget to your layout folder

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<SearchView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/edit_query"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textFilter"
    >

</SearchView>
```

Then, in your activity, retrieve the action bar

```
android.support.v7.app.ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
```

Then add a reference to your search view

```
 actionBar.setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar);
    search = (EditText) actionBar.getCustomView().findViewById(
            R.id.edit_query);
```

Then, set the display option for the action bar

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM | ActionBar.DISPLAY_HOME_AS_UP);
```

That's it.

Btw, you could also use my [search widget](https://github.com/riyagayasen/Easy_Search_Widget_Android) which takes a list of strings as an array list and displays them, according to the query entered. Once the user selects a particular result, the selected result is returned which can retrieved on the onActivityResult of the parent activity.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is triggered by a missing intent filter:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
</intent-filter>
```