# SearchView getActionView returning null

Tags: android, android-searchmanager, android-support-library

This was working a few days ago, but suddenly it stopped. I only want to use the action bar search widget when certain fragment is visible.

Now I'm unable to get the `SearchView`, now `getActionView` always returns null.

**searchable.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:hint="@string/search_for_places">
</searchable>
```

**Manifest.xml**

```
<activity
    android:name=".ui.activities.MainActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleTop">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH"/>
    </intent-filter>
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable"/>
    <meta-data
    android:name="android.app.default_searchable"
    android:value=".ui.activities.MainActivity" />
</activity>
```

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  xmlns:myapp="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_search_place"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_2_action_search"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title="@string/title_search"
        myapp:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
        myapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

**The fragment**

```
...
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
...



@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu, final MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search_place);
    mSearchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getBaseActivity().getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    if (mSearchView != null) {
        mSearchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getActivity().getComponentName()));
        mSearchView.setIconifiedByDefault(true);
        mSearchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    }
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Today I had the same problem and I think I solved it. It turns out I did couple of things that were not exactly as per the `ActionBarCompat` contract:

- Each activity that uses the `ActionBarCompat` should extend [`ActionBarActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) instead of `FragmentActivity` directly
- Each activity that uses the `ActionBarCompat` should declare its theme as inheriting from the `ActionBarCompat` themes.

Both of those I found watching the [explanation video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6TGgYqfJnyc&feature=youtu.be) from Google.

Now my `searchView` is not `null` anymore.

Comment: It solved my issue by using theme `Theme.AppCompat` instead of `Theme.Base.AppCompat`

Comment: My issue was Proguard. If you have Proguard enabled, make sure you have a rule that keeps the `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`. For example, to keep everything in all the different versions of the support library, add `-keep class android.support.** { *; }` and `-keep interface android.support.** { *; }`.

Comment: specifying the action class helped my situation:
`app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuView"`

Comment: @kip2 the `app:` solved my issue with not using the support.v7 also. Thanks!

Comment: @ashughes Your proguard answer should be theanswer. Thanks heaps! :)

Answer (score 114):

I had the same problem because in my menu I used:
`android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`
as per the google documentation.

Well it turns out that if I'm using AppCompatActivity I should use
`app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"`
instead.

Comment: I used `app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`

Comment: Lifesaver! Been searching for hours! Hopefully, they update their docs soon. Usually, their docs are pretty good.

Answer (score 32):

If you're using proguard this is the possible answer: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58508

In short, add below line to your proguard config file `proguard-rules.pro`.

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Comment: Pretty obvious, but I'll still mention - In case you have extended the SearchView to another class, keep the path to that class in proguard!

Comment: Thanks Man . I was facing this issue since 3 days . made all the changes but couldn't identify the bug . This was the problem.

Answer (score 9):

I fixed it: in the menu xml, I used the `app` namespace

For users of androidx libraries:

```xml
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    app:actionViewClass="androidx.appcompat.widget.SearchView"
```

For users of the older support libraries:

```xml
    app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
    app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
```

The Android tutorial, https://developer.android.com/training/search/setup.html, uses the framework `SearchView` rather than the androidx/support library one, and so it uses `android:showAs` and `android:actionView`

Answer (score 1):

[image: Change in the import]Changing to import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView helped me

Answer (score 0):

I was with the same error. And i've made the following things:

I have an Activity extending by FragmentActivity:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feed, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

**Searchable.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<searchable xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:label="@string/app_label"
    android:hint="@string/search_hint" >
</searchable>
```

**Menu.xml:**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="br.com.srtorcedor.FeedActivity">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
        android:title="@string/search_title"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>

</menu>
```

**AndroidManifest:**

```
  <activity
        android:name=".FeedActivity"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_pins"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_feed">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />
        </intent-filter>
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
    </activity>
```

Could you check if it works with you?

Answer (score 0):

Today I figured out that I was getting null from the getActionView() call on items that did not have:

```
android:showAsAction="always"
```

It seems otherwise they just don't inflate correctly.

Answer (score 0):

For me the following solution worked:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.dev.ttburger.conttagem.BuscarProdutoActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Buscar"
        app:showAsAction="always"   
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Change to:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.dev.ttburger.conttagem.BuscarProdutoActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="Buscar"
        app:showAsAction="always"   
        app:actionViewClass="android.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added this too:

```
setHasOptionsMenu(true);
```

Working with this and **@maxandron** answer