# MenuItemCompat.getActionView always returns null

Tags: android, searchview, android-actionbar-compat, android-search

I just implemented the `v7 AppCompat` support library but the `MenuItemCompat.getActionView` always return null in every Android version I tested (4.2.2, 2.3.4 ....)

The `SearchView` is displayed in action bar but it doesn't respond to touch actions and doesn't expand to show its `EditText` and is just like a simple icon.

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
    if (searchView != null) {
        SearchViewCompat.setOnQueryTextListener(searchView, mOnQueryTextListener);
        searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
        Log.d(TAG,"SearchView not null");
    } else
        Log.d(TAG, "SearchView is null");
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**Menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
          app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
          android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
          android:title="@string/action_bar_search"
          android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>

    <item android:id="@+id/action_refresh"
          android:icon="@drawable/refresh"
          android:title="@string/action_bar_refresh"
          app:showAsAction="ifRoom"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 296, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.

1. Changing namespace of `actionViewClass` from `android:actionViewClass` to `app:actionViewClass`
2. Implementing  `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener` interface for current activity.
3. Directly use `setOnQueryTextListener` instead of `SearchViewCompat.setOnQueryTextListener`

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
     MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
     inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);

     MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
     SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);
     if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
     }

     return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
   }
   ```

Comment: If this solved your problem you should probably accept your answer. I would also like to point all the other people with similar problems to one more thread discussing similar issues: http://stackoverflow.com/q/18407171/1108032. If the current thread does not solve your problems, consider looking into the solutions there.

Comment: Great answer!  It might pay to clarify too that the "app" in app:actionViewClass also requires an additional xmlns declaration for the "app" namespace.

Comment: Need to say that `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` class should not be confused with 'android.support.v4.widget.SearchViewCompat' class (which is known as a common mistake when using ActionBarCompat library)

Comment: Your namespace hint solved my issue :) This was the missing puzzle piece.

Comment: @jklp I try to add xmlns declaration `<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >` but get error `Attribute is missing the Android namespace prefix`. Do you get it, and how do you fix it?

Comment: Also note, android:showAsAction needs to be changed to app:showAsAction as well. Also make sure your theme for the activity (not just the application) is referencing an appcompat theme. Last thing, the app declartion is "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

Comment: Actually point number 1 did the trick! Such a standard error, dammit, but I just didn't see it. Thanks so much, life saver!

Comment: My issue was Proguard. If you have Proguard enabled, make sure you have a rule that keeps the `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView`. For example, to keep everything in all the different versions of the support library, add `-keep class android.support.** { *; }` and `-keep interface android.support.** { *; }`.

Comment: Thanks guy, your response helps me a lot... Probably you have to add one point app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"

Comment: 1. Changing namespace of actionViewClass from android:actionViewClass to app:actionViewClass works for me, thanks!

Comment: Extra comment for the visitors: If still the above have not worked for you, delete the application from your device/emulator, and run the following gradle tasks (clean, build) and then deploy (possibly using assembleDebug)

Answer (score 84):

In my case it was ProGuard file. You need to add this line:

```
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
```

Comment: Wow, why is this a thing? This was the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: +1. Pretty obvious, but I'll still mention - In case you have extended the SearchView to another class, keep the path to that class in proguard!

Answer (score 42):

For me, an incorrect `menu.xml` namespace import caused this problem.

My original `menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
        <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
              android:title="@string/map_option_search"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
              app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
              app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

It looks like the `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` was causing `MenuItemCompat.getActionView()` to return `null`.  Changing this import to `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` fixed the problem.

New working `menu.xml`:

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
       <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
              android:title="@string/map_option_search"
              android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
              app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|ifRoom"
              app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

Answer (score 5):

I think that the problem is that you use the SearchView from the Support V7 package and maybe your API level is set to.....22??.

Changing your code to the following in order to fix the problem:

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item 
        android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/actionbar_button_search"
        android:title="Search"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Comment: Could you explain why the code sample you provided solves the problem? (I assume it does.)

Answer (score 4):

I was with the same error, my method `getActionView()` was always returning null. So, I've made the following things:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
      android:icon="@drawable/abc_ic_search"
      android:title="@string/search_title"
      android:showAsAction="always"
      android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView"/>
```

I saw in some posts that the people are using app: or yourapp, but i've used normally `android:ActionVewClass`.

On my `onCreateOptionsMenu` method:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.feed, menu);

    // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
    SearchManager searchManager = 
        (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.action_search)
            .getActionView();
    searchView.setSearchableInfo(searchManager
            .getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

    return true;
}
```

And do not forget to put in the `onCreate` method:

```
// enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
```

This works very well for my activity "extending" for `FragmentActivity` and `ActionBarActivity`.

Answer (score 2):

Mohsen Afshin's answer above was my starting point and I made some tweaks to get it working with my setup:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    // SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat
    //    .getActionView(searchItem);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) searchItem.getActionView();
    if (searchView != null) {
        searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String s) {
                // do something with s, the entered string
                query = s;
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "String entered is " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String s) {
                return false;
            }
        });
    }
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

**menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:title="Search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom|collapseActionView"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did this by manual set in java code:

```
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/user_info"
        android:title="@string/user_name_title"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_item_username"
        android:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="200dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/usr_name_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/user_info_image_des"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:paddingStart="10dp"
        android:paddingEnd="10dp"
        android:text="@string/user_name_title"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Then in java code:

```
    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.connect_menu, menu);
        // show user name on the top of menu
        Log.e("menu", "Size: " + menu.size());
        MenuItem item = menu.getItem(0);
        item.setActionView(R.layout.menu_item_username);
        View v = item.getActionView();
        if (null == v) {
            Log.e("NULL POINTER EX", "NULL MENU VIEW");
        } else {
            TextView usrNameTitle = v.findViewById(R.id.usr_name_title);
            if (null != usrName && usrName.length() > 0) {
                usrNameTitle.setText(usrName);
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same code, but instead of using the import `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;` I was using `import android.widget.SearchView;` . This fixed my problem with the `null` value. 
So just change this code in your search activity and it will work and also change the namespace in xml file.

Comment: This was our issue, we had a mix of android.widget.SearchView in the Activity but had a partial use of v7 in our menu_main.xml file. Just make sure the .xml file is also using app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" too.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet of how to handle the searchView from support library v7 :

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(final Menu menu,final MenuInflater inflater)
  {
  menu.clear();
  getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(...,menu);
  _searchView=(SearchView)MenuItemCompat.getActionView(_searchMenuItem);
  _searchView.setQueryHint(...);

  if(VERSION.SDK_INT<VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    {
    final EditText searchTextView=(EditText)searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    if(searchTextView!=null)
      {
      searchTextView.setScroller(new Scroller(_context));
      searchTextView.setMaxLines(1);
      searchTextView.setVerticalScrollBarEnabled(true);
      searchTextView.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
      searchTextView.setTextColor(_context.getResources().getColor(App.getResIdFromAttribute(_context,android.R.attr.textColorPrimary)));
      }
    }
  _searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener()
    {
    ...
    });
  MenuItemCompat.setActionView(_searchMenuItem,_searchView);
  MenuItemCompat.setOnActionExpandListener(_searchMenuItem,new OnActionExpandListener()
    {
    ...
    });
  super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu,inflater);
  }


public static int getResIdFromAttribute(final Activity activity,final int attr)
  {
  if(attr==0)
    return 0;
  final TypedValue typedvalueattr=new TypedValue();
  activity.getTheme().resolveAttribute(attr,typedvalueattr,true);
  return typedvalueattr.resourceId;
  }
```

Also, if you use Proguard, add this to its configuration :

```
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep class android.support.v7.widget.SearchView { *; }
-keepattributes *Annotation*
```

Comment: To whoever wanted to format the code, this is a very known formatting called "WhiteSmith". Changing to another format doesn't make it better, as this is a matter of taste.

Comment: @JJD Yes. Correct. It's not as common as others, but I've used it for a very long time. You can set it on Eclipse if you wish.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I stay with the default since it avoids a lot unwanted discussions with team members or contributors.

Comment: @JJD That's also true. at the office we work with a bit different style than the default one. Anyway, a good developer should be able to handle all of the common formatting styles, and if it "hurts the eyes" you can always copy the code and format it on various formatting tools (online, or on the IDE).

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue with the difference being I was attempting to use a class that extended `android.widget.ImageView`

If you're using ProGuard, you need to specify to allow the methods involved in this class.

```
-keep public class * extends android.widget.ImageView{
  public <init>(android.content.Context);
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet);
  public <init>(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int);
  public void set*(...);
}
```

http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/examples.html

This says, "Allow all needed constructors that might be called from xml and allow any custom setters it uses as well (add more as needed)"

Answer (score -1):

Remove code: 
public class DemoActivity extends **ActionBarActivity**

Replace by:
public class DemoActivity extends **Activity**

Comment: Why should he do so? Please explain your answer a bit more in detail.

Comment: When I extends ActionBarActivity, it alway return null. But I extends Activity only, it work normal

Comment: You need to use your own namespace when using ActionBarActivity as it is a part of support library. Since you're using android:showAsAction in your xml it works with Activity (which is not from support library) and doesn't work with ActionBarActivity