# getActionView return null in appcompat 7 actionbar

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am using appcompat 7 instead of sherlockactionbar. Now i want to add update counter button in actionbar but return null getActionView in onCreateOptionsMenu function. My code is:

```
MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
View count = menu.findItem(R.id.update).getActionView();
TextView notifCount = (TextView) count.findViewById(R.id.textOne);
if(mNotifCount<=0) notifCount.setVisibility(View.GONE);
notifCount.setText(String.valueOf(mNotifCount));
return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
```

My menu.xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
tools:context=".MainActivity">
<item android:id="@+id/action_example" android:title="@string/action_example"
    app:showAsAction="withText|ifRoom" />
<item android:id="@+id/action_settings" android:title="@string/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100" app:showAsAction="never" />
<item
    android:title="update"
    android:id="@+id/update"
    android:actionLayout="@layout/feed_update_count"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    android:orderInCategory="0" />
```

Comment: Try suggestions in [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18557789/1777090) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18439753/1777090)

Answer (score 4):

Change `android:actionLayout` to `app:actionLayout` and use `MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem...);`

Answer (score 0):

You'll likely need to use MenuItemCompat to load the actionview;

```
SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menu.findItem(R.id.action_search));
```

Comment: Tried that, still null. The menu item has attribute: `android:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"`