# onCreateOptionsMenu () method throws null pointer when support search widget is used

Tags: android, widget, searchview

## Activity

with #import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;

```
  @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.search_menu, menu);

        // Associate searchable configuration with the SearchView
        SearchManager searchManager =
                (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);
        SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(getComponentName()));

        return true;
    }
```

## search_menu xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:title="search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
        yourapp:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" />
</menu>
```

when i use support search view it throws an null pointer

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at .MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:42)
        at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2585)
        at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:378)
        at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:94)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$AppCompatWindowCallback.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:2549)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.preparePanel(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1589)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.doInvalidatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1869)
        at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl$2.run(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:230)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:103)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5333)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:828)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:644)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

but when i change the xml to search widget instead of support widget as follows and change the import on activity

#import android.widget.SearchView;

all works fine

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:yourapp="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <item android:id="@+id/search"
        android:title="search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:showAsAction="collapseActionView|always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.widget.SearchView" />
```

null poitner shows on this line if it helps

```
SearchView searchView =
                (SearchView) menu.findItem(R.id.search).getActionView();
```

i have checked the available suggested  solutions ..but none of them works..some soulutions are deprecated now

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SearchView getActionView returning null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407171/searchview-getactionview-returning-null)

Comment: @varunkr ..thanks man..for helping out..

Comment: @varunkr   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18407171/searchview-getactionview-returning-null    this does not fix my issue..i have alredy done all in the  above  code

Comment: i think most suitable answer is here   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18832890/android-nullpointerexception-on-searchview-in-action-bar/18942838#18942838   and this clears the logic behind the exception..but the fix is deprecated now