# How to do a search with SearchWidget

Tags: java, android, searchview

I have already set up the search widget on the action bar as per viperbone's answer on [How to add a SearchWidget to the ActionBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11276043/how-to-add-a-searchwidget-to-the-actionbar), however I don't know what to put in the Search class to process the query.

All the items I want to search are in a simple ArrayList of Strings. I can handle the comparator, I just don't know how to pass the ArrayList and the query to the class to process it.

Please don't send me links, especially to the Android Developer site, because it is VERY confusing to me. I would really appreciate it if you could write some code for me to use specific to my situation.

Thanks in advance

Comment: @user2045570, I haven't tried anything yet. I really don't know where to start

Comment: Start by googling some tutorials. You have to try something first, this forum is for specific programming questions. We can't just post the answer for you. Look up some tutorials first before you ask a question.

Comment: All I'm asking is for someone to tell me how to pass the query and ArrayList to the Search class. I can do everything else

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using SearchView with ListView then try following code:

```
listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
searchView.setIconifiedByDefault(false);
searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
searchView.setSubmitButtonEnabled(true);
searchView.setQueryHint("Search...");


@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(newText)) {
        listView.clearTextFilter();
    } else {
        listView.setFilterText(newText.toString());
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Your answer was actually better than what I was trying to do! Thanks