# java.lang.NullPointerException SearchView OnCreateOptionsMenu

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-actionbar-compat, android-search, android-searchmanager

I am trying to make my app work for Gingerbread (API 10). My app crashes when I click on the menu with following error -

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.sample.appdemo.onCreateOptionsMenu(AppDemoListActivity.java:83)
```

My app worked fine with API 11 and higher in the past. Anyone please help?

Here is what I have:

**build.gradle**:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sample.appdemo"
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':poi-3.10-FINAL-20140208')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:21.0.3'
}
```

**AppDemoListActivity.java**

```
    package ...;
    import android.app.SearchManager;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.view.MenuItemCompat;
    import android.support.v7.widget.SearchView;
    import ...;

    @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.action_bar_search_optionsmenu, menu);
            SearchManager searchManager = (SearchManager) getSystemService(Context.SEARCH_SERVICE);

        MenuItem searchItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
        SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchItem);

        ComponentName cn = new ComponentName(this, SearchActivity.class);
        searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn)
        );

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }
```

**action_bar_search_menu:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/action_search"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
        android:title="@string/action_search"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"/>
</menu>
```

**Update # 1:**

**Manifest:**

```
<activity
    android:name=".SearchActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_search"
    android:parentActivityName=".AppDemoListActivity" >

    <!-- This intent-filter identifies this activity as "searchable" -->

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEARCH" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>

    <!-- This metadata entry provides further configuration details for searches -->
    <!-- that are handled by this activity. -->

    <meta-data
        android:name="android.app.searchable"
        android:resource="@xml/searchable" />
</activity>
```

Comment: What is line 83 of `AppDemoListActivity.java`?

Comment: Line83: searchView.setSearchableInfo(
                searchManager.getSearchableInfo(cn)
        );

Comment: And the `SearchActivity.class` already exist and is registered in you Manifest???

Comment: yes. I wil add an update with manifest

Comment: Potential duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11276043/4193263

Comment: ByteHamster: I did come across that post but unfortunately that fix which I already have in code didn't work :(

Comment: could anyone please help?